# UPDATE table with NULL instead of 0 kills connection to server

Tags: sql, postgresql, null, sql-update

In PostgreSQL 12.1 on macOS 14.5, I'm trying to replace zeros with NULL in a table of about 250 million rows. About 8 million rows need updating. The table has no foreign keys, private key, or triggers etc. When I run:

```
UPDATE table
SET column = NULL
WHERE column = 0;
```

The connection to server gets killed by `server process (PID xxx) was terminated by signal 9: Killed: 9`, which I understand can be an OOM problem.

I deleted all indexes of the table, which brought down the "cost" (running `EXPLAIN`) from 7 digits to 0.00, however the command still doesn't work. I'm using a home laptop with 16gb of memory.

The log of running the command (with the indexes deleted) is:

```
2020-02-17 09:31:08.626 CET [94908] LOG:  server process (PID xxx) was terminated by signal 9: Killed: 9
2020-02-17 09:31:08.626 CET [94908] DETAIL:  Failed process was running: update tablename
        set columnname = NULL
        where columnname = 0;

2020-02-17 09:31:08.626 CET [94908] LOG:  terminating any other active server processes
2020-02-17 09:31:08.626 CET [94919] WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
2020-02-17 09:31:08.626 CET [94919] DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exi$
2020-02-17 09:31:08.626 CET [94919] HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.
2020-02-17 09:31:08.626 CET [94914] WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
2020-02-17 09:31:08.626 CET [94914] DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exi$
2020-02-17 09:31:08.626 CET [94914] HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.
2020-02-17 09:31:08.629 CET [94908] LOG:  all server processes terminated; reinitializing
2020-02-17 09:31:08.698 CET [94927] LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2020-02-17 09:30:57 CET
2020-02-17 09:31:08.901 CET [94927] LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress
2020-02-17 09:31:08.906 CET [94927] LOG:  invalid record length at 17/894C438: wanted 24, got 0
2020-02-17 09:31:08.906 CET [94927] LOG:  redo is not required
```

How can I update the table? Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any messages in the logfile? What is your **exact** Postgres version? (`select version();` will tell you). Do you have any replication running?

Comment: Thanks for you comment. I updated the question with the log output and postgres version. I'm running 12.1.

Comment: Does the table have triggers or foreign key constraints?

Comment: No, there are no foreign keys or triggers. There is also no private key.

Comment: Which os are you running on?

Comment: Macos 14.5. Postgresql not installed via homebrew.